# if condition and would

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would

Consider the following two sentences:

1. If I had a free year, I would have traveled the world.
2. If I had a free year, I would travel the world.

Is sentence 1 referring past not probable thing?

Is sentence 2 referring present not probable thing? i.e. I don't have a free year now, so I can't travel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence isn't really correct. It should read:

> If I **had had** a free year, I would have traveled the world.

(In everyday speech, it is often spoken the way you wrote it, with a single *had.* I think it's more often spoken correctly, but both are common.)

It's called the [third conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Third_conditional); it refers to a hypothetical situation in the past, which (since it has already failed to happen) is really an impossibility.

Sentence #2 is an example of the [second conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional)—exactly as you say, it's something that would be in the present, but is actually not probable.

Comment: Yes, nicely answered.  *I never could hold on to money.  If **I'd had** a million dollars when I was a young man, I'd still be a poor man today.*  I agree many would avoid the double "had" but it sounds more elegant to me.

Comment: @Andrew I think that's what I hear the most, actually -- people contracting the first _had,_ but including them both.